# Share store/actions between Redux instances

Tags: redux, react-redux, store, middleware, redux-middleware

Is there a way to share the redux store between multiple React/Redux instances on the same page?

The content of my webpage is provided by a CMS. I want to include several React widgets on the page, but the problem is that each instance has its own store.

to illustrate: after config of the webpage by the CMS it will provide anchor divs into the page like this:

```html
<div id='my-react-widget-A'></div>
<div id='my-react-widget-B'></div>
<div id='my-react-widget-C'></div>
```

I heard about ways to publish actions through middleware, but most of the solutions I found are to publish them over a network connection, I would like to keep them on the same page.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of data you want to have in sync between different apps?

Comment: Goes against Redux principles as a single source of truth